# which JS function is triggered by a click on html element

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML sidebar and I wanted to change the icon for opening/closing the sidebar

My HTML code is :

```
<li class="sidebar-toggler-wrapper">
            <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
            <div class="sidebar-toggler">
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
            <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
        </li>
```

The element with the class `sidebar-toggler` is the one I click to open/close the sidebar. As you can see, there is no html that define the icon (ex: `<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>`). So there is somewhere a JS code that set and change this icon but i can't find this js/line.

I guess there is an option in Google Chrome Inspector or Firebug that can show all events triggered in a web page or something like this?

I searched in all my project for something like "$('.sidebar-toggler')" but didn't find something interesting.

## Update

A search on 'sidebar-toggler' gives me this code, nut not trace of icon handling

```
// handle the search submit
    $('.sidebar-search .submit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('body').hasClass("page-sidebar-closed")) {
            if ($('.sidebar-search').hasClass('open') == false) {
                if ($('.page-sidebar-fixed').size() === 1) {
                    $('.page-sidebar .sidebar-toggler').click(); //trigger sidebar toggle button
                }
                $('.sidebar-search').addClass("open");
            } else {
                $('.sidebar-search').submit();
            }
        } else {
            $('.sidebar-search').submit();
        }
    });`
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: We can't **possibly** know what code is getting triggered unless you **show** us that code. Though based on the classes I assume it's something in Font Awesome / Bootstrap.

Comment: Please spend some time reviewing [ask] and update your question to include a [mcve] otherwise it's [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: @zzzzBov I added some code example.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I submited the part of the code using bootstrap template

Answer (score 1):

Chrome devtools does have a feature to help with this situation -- where you know an event is firing, but you don't what what code is running as a result.

See the screenshot further below for reference.

1. Open the **Sources** tab (you might have to click the arrow to see it).
2. In the bottom-left panel, expand the section titled **Event Listener Breakpoints**, then expand the **Mouse** subsection, then check the **click** box. This will cause the Chrome debugger to pause on any click events. Now click the element on the page and Chrome will enter debugging mode.
3. There may be multiple handlers called, some which you don't care about. Use the blue **resume script execution** button and/or the controls next to it do dig into the running code and search for what you care about. Be prepared to wade through a bunch of jQuery library code :)

[image: Devtools screenshot]

If you're new to Chrome's debugger, this can be a bit daunting at first. You may go through a few cycles where you miss what you want and the browser resumes normal operation. If that happens, just click the `#toto` element to start over, and try again.

Check out [this great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0XScE08hy8) the Google Chrome Developers YouTube channel posted on debugging a few months ago (Jan 2018). It's short (8min) but very educational.

There is also an awesome feature in the latest version of Chrome (66) that allows you to blackbox a script from the callstack when the debugger is paused. If you have Chrome 66 installed and you're stuck in a bunch of jQuery code, find `jquery.min.js` in the **Callstack** pane, right-click it, select **Blackbox script**, then retrigger the click breakpoint. Chrome should now bypass the jQuery code, making it much easier to find what you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! I tested your solution, the debugger goes trougth Jquery but didn't find the script that change the icon :(

Comment: If that failed, it might be worth experimenting with DOM breakpoints. One easy way to set these is to find the `<div class="sidebar-toggler">` element in the **Elements** inspector, right click it, and select **break on > subtree modifications**. Then click the element on the page, the debugger should pause, and you can search from there. You can also try a search for just `sidebar-toggler` in your code. Someone may have used a delegated event listener, or double quotes, or any other small change that wouldn't match the exact term you tried searching for. Searching for less can yield more.

Comment: I find a bunch of code (I updated my post) but there is no mention of icon handling, may this is handled elsewhere than in JS?

Comment: At this point I'm not sure I can help further. Event listener and/or DOM breakpoints will most certainly reveal the code you're looking for, but using them well can be a bit of an art. If you haven't watched the YouTube video I linked in my answer, I highly recommend it. They do a better job of showing how to use the debugger features than I can here. In addition to skipping over event callbacks with the blue arrow, you'll have to step into functions as well to fully explore the call stacks. I just can't instruct you on when exactly to click which button and how far to go, you have to explore.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your explanation. I'll try all of this and come back to you if needed.